# Can I pass parameter to a 2sxc SQL data source

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

Say that I have a large SQL table.  I want to get specific data out of the table and into a 2sxc module.

SQL Query:

select * from myTable where dataCategory=

What I need to do is pass  from the 2sxc module down into the data source.

Is that possible?  The parameter will come to the module as a querystring value.

Answer (score 0):

No problem :)

Use something like `Select * from myTable where dataCategory = [QueryString:category]`

You'll have to check if you need to wrap it in quotes like `'[QueryString:category]'` or without the quotes, I think it's without the quotes.

The sql data source even does additional parsing to ensure you're protected from SQL inject. So internally it actually converts it to a `Select ... where dataCategory = @p1` and then tells the server that `@p1 = 'cake'` or whatever was in the url.

Comment: Is it also possible to pass a razor variable to the query?

Comment: razor params to visual query don't work yet. it's something we're considering - because we also want to be able to call queries from queries, so we'll need a parameter system. But it's still completely open.